# open 5 instances of chrome with different urls on selenium grid?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, promise

I have a json file of urls as follows:

```
 {
  "urls": [
    "http://www.google.com/",
    "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
  ]
}
```

All these urls are opened by the selenium webdriver javascript manager in sequence one after another. This is being done on a selenium grid.

Is it possible to fire up say 2 different chrome instances with the above 2 urls in parallel on the selenium grid?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its very much possible. You need to have 2 web-driver scripts to start 2 different URLs in separate ports of node within `selenium grid`.

Run these commands on the machine you want to run as node with different port numbers.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -host localhost -port 5555 -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS
```

If you need 2 scripts to run, start two commands with different port numbers e.g. (5555 and 5556).

And use 2 different ports in separate web-driver scripts;

```
def setUp(self):

         self.browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities = {"browserName": 'firefox', "node": '5555'})
```